Polly Circuit-breaker propogates 500 error but not 5xx+ in http calls
HttpConsentCircuitBreakerPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
   .HandleTransientHttpError()
   .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
   .CircuitBreakerAsync(3,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), OnBreak, OnReset);

Why am I getting different behaviour when http results is 500 and BrokenCircuitException contains InnerException and propogates 500 http error, but statusCode > 500 does NOT have InnerException and does NOT propagate the http error?

Did my post clarify the observed behaviour?

Your policy triggers only if the decorated method:

throws an HttpRequestException (source)
throws an TimeoutRejectedException
returns an HttpResponseMessage with a status code 408 (source)
returns an HttpResponseMessage with a status code greater or equal to 500 source)

Ever other thrown exception or returned HttpResponseMessage does not count into the the consecutive failure count.
